# admin backend template (CP styles) not fully showing

Tags: control-panel, admin

Hi Folk I'm trying to learn the basics of EE2 and have setup a test rig using MAMP PRO I got everything working. I'm basically converting one of my basic static websites into a EE2 driven site.
However when I tried to login to the admin area yesterday I've seem to be missing most of the formatting i.e I can still login however the back-end interface is mostly missing. the front end is still working okay. What do you think has happened and how do I get the back-end fully back with out doing a full install again?

Jonathan

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that the control panel pages appear without style and formatting this sounds like a path issue.

In the control panel, go to *Admin > General Configuration* and check the **URL to your "themes" folder** and **Theme Folder Path** are both correct.

If that's not it, then I'd double check the permissions on the themes folder.

You can also use your web inspector console to check for errors.

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the advice I try this out tonight.

Comment: Hi Alex it work! Thanks I really appreciate your support. Jonathan

Comment: Jonathan, don't forget to select Alex's answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left.